# how to start an activity that allows the user to pick a pdf from office lens and receive it

Tags: android

1. I want to add functionality for the user to pick pdf from microsoft office lens and send it to my application by the help of `startActivityForResult()` method. Is it possible?
2. The following code allows the user to navigate from my application to playstore and then office lens. How do i navigate the user directly to office lens

   ```
   val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.microsoft.office.officelens"))
   intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
   startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK_CODE)
   ```

Comment: `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` does not allow to select Content from 3rd party apps . You can try using `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` with Package name of this app . But first check if app is installed or not .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I found the comment useful and came up with this to solve my second problem

```
val isAppInstalled = appInstalledOrNot("com.microsoft.office.officelens")
        if (isAppInstalled)
        {
            //This intent will help you to launch if the package is already installed
            Toast.makeText(this@ScrollingActivity, "Its toast at if!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.microsoft.office.officelens")
    startActivityForResult(LaunchIntent, IMAGE_PICK_CODE)
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this@ScrollingActivity, "else executed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.microsoft.office.officelens"))
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK_CODE)

        }
```

this function lets you to check if the application is installed or not

```
 private fun appInstalledOrNot(uri:String):Boolean {
        val pm = getPackageManager()
        try
        {
            pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)
            return true
        }
        catch (e:PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {}
        return false
    }
```